# Checking existence of an array inside an array of arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of arrays:

```
qv=array([[-1.075, -1.075, -3.   ],
       [-1.05 , -1.075, -3.   ],
       [-1.025, -1.075, -3.   ],
       ..., 
       [-0.975, -0.925, -2.   ],
       [-0.95 , -0.925, -2.   ],
       [-0.925, -0.925, -2.   ]])
```

And I want to determine if an array is contained in that 2-D array and return its index.

```
qt=array([-1.  , -1.05, -3.  ])
```

I can convert both arrays to lists and use the list.index() function:

```
qlist=qv.tolist()
ql=qt.tolist()
qindex=qlist.index(ql)
```

But I would like to avoid doing this because I think it will be a performance hit.

Comment: don't "think it will be a performance hit". measure.

Comment: I will.  Once it becomes clear how to do it using numpy instead of lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick,

```
import numpy as np
np.where((qv == qt).all(-1))
```

Or

```
import numpy as np
tol = 1e-8
diff = (qv - qt)
np.where((abs(diff) < tol).all(-1))
```

The second method might be more appropriate when floating point precision issues come into play. Also, there might be a better approach if you have many `qt` to test against. For example `scipy.spatial.KDTree`.

Comment: Hooray!  +1 for floating point considerations. For my particular test set, %timeit in ipython shows that your method is 30.5 ns, vs 770 us for the list method. Thanks!